# How do you open that window of code suggestions?

Tags: sublimetext

[Autofill windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2FeH.png)

You can open it and see the options even without typing something, but how?

Comment: Please take the hashtags out of your title.

Comment: @Brien You could have done that yourself...

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe agreed, but if I did it for them then there is no learning opportunity. I’ll fix posts where the end result is a question worth keeping, but this one never had a chance.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks! By pressing ctrl + space it pops up the auto suggestion list ~ Nice!